# How to parse SOAP in order to list all Request and Object names

Tags: php, soap, xpath, namespaces, simplexml

I'm able to parse an XML SOAP when I know Namespace and Request name.

Because I have different kind of SOAP requests, I would like to get the Request name in the SOAP file . Extract of a part of my SOAP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:ns1="http://schema.example.com" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 **<ns1:SendMailling>**
 <campagne xsi:type="ns1:Campaign"><ActivateDedup xsi:nil="true"/><BillingCode     xsi:nil="true"/><DeliveryFax xsi:type="ns1:DeliveryFax"/>
 <DeliveryMail xsi:type="ns1:DeliveryMail">
 ...
```

PHP Code:

```
if(is_file($file))
    {
        $content=file_get_contents($file);


        $xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://schema.example.com');



        foreach ($xml->xpath('\\SOAP-ENV:') as $item)
        {
            //certainly the bad way?
            echo "<pre>";
                print_r($item);
            echo "</pre>";

        }

        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($xml);
        echo "</pre>";


    }
```

I get no result... I would like to make appears : 'SendMailling' (identify the request name)

When I specifically specify

```
//foreach($xml->xpath('//ns1:SendMailling') as $item)
```

there is no problems.

I tried  `foreach($xml->xpath('//ns1') as $item)`
and `$xml->xpath('//SOAP-ENC'), $xml->xpath('//Body')` but...

Comment: So your actualy question is that you would like to know how you can get a list of used namespaces in the XML document? - http://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php

Answer (score 0):

> *I had problems to understand your questions so this probably is not the answer.*

If I understand you right, you want to select all Element Nodes that are a direct children of `<SOAP-ENV:Body>` and that are in the `ns1` / `http://schema.example.com` namespace.

You already have registered the namespace prefix to be used with `SimpleXMLElement::xpath`:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://schema.example.com');
```

You have not yet registered the `SOAP-ENV` /  `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` namespace as far as I can see.

In XPath to match an element you can specify it's namespace. There are multiple ways how this is done:

```
*               All elements in any namespace.
prefix:*        All elements in namespace "prefix" (registered prefix)
prefix:local    Only "local" elements in namespace "prefix"
```

For example to select all elements with the `ns1` prefix:

```
//ns1:*
```

You might want to limit this because you only want direct children withn `<SOAP-ENV:Body>`  so register that namespace with the `SOAP-ENV` prefix and extend the previous xpath:

```
/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:*
```

This should then have all those elements you're looking for.

---

(OP:) Thanks again, when I do a

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:*') as $item) {
    echo $item->getName() . "<br>";
}
```

All is ok I get the request Name `'SendMailling'`.

Comment: @Gilles, please accept the answer if it helped you. You know how accepting an answer works? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work